# How to wrap and show views in common tabs layout?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

How to create and use a common layout to show in it dynamically `signinView` or `signupView` according to the action?

Current solution needs improvement because it has two layouts with separate templates for each view, templates are differ only in `%li.active` and layout `tabContent` region is also filled on show with right view.

I created jsfiddle demo: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/g9gfuwuk/1/)

Module is listening to `auth:tab:switchviews` event and call right action from API.

```
define [
  "app"
  "marionette"
  "apps/auth/authLayout"
  "apps/auth/signin/signin_controller"
  "apps/auth/signin/signup_controller"
], (app, Marionette, authLayout, signinController, signupController) ->
  AuthApp = app.module("AuthApp", (AuthApp) ->
    AuthApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend

      API =
        signin: ->
          new AuthApp.Signin.Controller
            region: app.dialog

        signup: ->
          new AuthApp.Signup.Controller
            region: app.dialog

    AuthApp.on "auth:tab:switchviews", (name) ->
      if name is "signin"
        API.signin()
      else
        API.signup()

    app.on "auth:signin", ->
      API.signin()
```

For `signupView` and `signinView` controllers looks similarly so I pasted only signup:

```
define [
  "app"
  "apps/auth/signup/signup_view"
  "apps/auth/signup/authentication_layout_for_signup"
  "models/registration"
], (App, signupView, signupAuthenticationLayout, Registration) ->
  "use strict"
  App.module "AuthApp.Signup", (Signup, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    Signup.Controller = App.Controllers.Base.extend
      initialize: (options) ->
        registration_model = new App.Entities.Registration()

        @layout = new signupAuthenticationLayout()

        new signupView.Signup
          model: registration_model  

        @layout.tabContent.show editView

  App.AuthApp.Signup.Controller
```

Marionette `triggers:` doesn't pass `data-content` so I handle it using `events:`, below layout for signup:

```
define [
  "marionette"
  "app"
  "apps/auth/templates/signupAuthTpl"
], (Marionette, app, signupAuthTpl) ->
  "use strict"
  Marionette.Layout.extend
    template: signupAuthTpl
    regions:
      tabContent: "#tab-content"
    events:
      "click ul.nav-tabs li a": "switchViews"
    switchViews: (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
      @curTab = $(e.target).data("content")
      app.AuthApp.trigger "auth:tab:switchviews", @curTab
```

Template for `signinView`:

```
.modal-dialog
  .modal-content
    .modal-header
      %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} &times;
    #auth-view-container
      %ul.nav.nav-tabs
        %li.active
          %a{"data-content" => "signin", "data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#login"} Login
        %li
          %a{"data-content" => "signup", "data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#signup"} Sign up
      #tab-content.tab-content
```

Template for `signupView`, notice that `.active` is in second list element:

```
.modal-dialog
  .modal-content
    .modal-header
      %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} &times;
    #auth-view-container
      %ul.nav.nav-tabs
        %li
          %a{"data-content" => "signin", "data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#login"} Login
        %li.active
          %a{"data-content" => "signup", "data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#signup"} Sign up
      #tab-content.tab-content
```

I'm learning Marionette.js but I could not find good example with use of module and layout with dynamic views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/eguneys/77frf1f2/

```
if (@curTab == 'signin')
  @tabContent.show (new authApp.signUpView())
else
  @tabContent.show (new authApp.signinView())
```

I omitted controllers, and didn't bother with active links, but you should easily integrate them, just get the idea.

Comment: @Bartek you mentioned you didn't like this answer, however this solves your main problem, if you need to find more information about how to use controllers in marionette ask another question, and accept this answer please.